# Using of Distinct by in dataweave for CSV output in mulesoft

Tags: csv, mule, distinct-values, dataweave

I am using data weave connector in my mule flow ..

Details:- From input side I am getting collection of array and I want to convert into CSV and write into the file.

But for particular column I am getting duplicates value and I want to remove them through data weaver.But when I am putting distinct by in front of that particular column ...code is not Woking and my getting below exception.

"Cannot coerce a :string to a :array"

Below is the mapping I am doing from output side.

```
dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
payload map ((value, index) -> {
   A1: $.A1 distinctBy $ ,
   B1 $.B1,
   C1: $.C1,
   D1: $.D1,
   E1: $.E1,
 F1: $.F1
```

))

Guys please let me know how to use distinct by for "A1 Column" or any trick to remove duplicates value for particular column inside the data weave even i have tried group by but same syntax error is coming.. :(

Cheers, Stevin

Answer (score 1):

Please find the same solution at [MuleSoft Forum](http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/37347/using-of-distinct-by-in-dataweave-for-csv-output.html#answer-37348)

Answer (score 1):

Use distinctBy $.A1 outside the map

```
dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
(payload map ((value, index) -> {
 A1: $.A1,
 B1 $.B1,
 C1: $.C1,
 D1: $.D1,
 E1: $.E1,
 F1: $.F1
 )) distinctBy $.A1
```